# Are there any Lion optimized text editors with VIM keybindings?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for a text editor with support for Lion's new features - specifically autosave, versions, and full-screen support.

I would also really like to be able to use VIM keybindings, either standard, or as an option. Does this combination exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2), it is still in beta and they have adding full-screen support in Lion but not others you mentioned.  And you can use [Vim key-binding](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/sublime-text-2-tips-and-tricks/) too.

[MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) is also working on some of the Lion refinements (the ones that are included have some rough edges) - it's certainly not stable since it's being fixed as the days go by, but as an open-source program, you can see the bugs/defects and know when the features you care are shipped or have issues.

Comment: Meh, its vim command mode movement bindings, its not real vim :( MacVim has lion support, so why not use that?

Comment: +1 for the MacVIM recommendation. Combine with the Janus project and it's a powerful editor.

Answer (score 1):

[Chocolat](http://chocolatapp.com/) is a Textmate style editor *(like Sublime still in Development)* that has **all** the Lion features.
Also vim mode was added in the latest version.

Personally I find Sublime's completion a lot better tho.

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe no-one mentioned [Vico](http://www.vicoapp.com/). It's a relatively new code editor sold on the App Store that uses vi keybindings and is scriptable using Nu.

[image]

It doesn't support auto-save or Versions but does support Lion's full screen and Resume.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 4 does allow you to take advantage of all the new Lion features at the expense of native vi/vim key commands. Mac text entry is more emacs like than vi like, but there are plenty of [good articles that explain how to customize the key bindings to make Xcode more vi like](http://weblog.highorderbit.com/post/3901744683/learning-to-leave-vim-and-embrace-xcode).

I find when I need heavy vi lifting, I drop into terminal and get the job done, but spend more and more time in Xcode due to the nature of the code I'm crafting.

Answer (score 0):

MacVim? It has lion support (the full screen). Is there a problem with that?

I think autosave & versions is not in the spec for vim :( so an alternative would be needed.

Answer (score -1):

I'm fairly sure there isn't anything (could be wrong, VIM makes my eyes glaze over), but that's probably best followed with a *yet*. A lot of devs seem to be scrambling to get updated with the new Lion calls.